# Minimum of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, fractions, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $0\leq x,y,z<1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. What is the minimum value of
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}?$$

From the condition, the point $(x,y,z)$ lies on a sphere with radius $1$. At the equality point, all three variables are equal to $1/\sqrt{3}$, and the value taken is $3/\sqrt{2}$. If one variable is $0$ and the other two are equal, the two variables are equal to $1/\sqrt{2}$, and the value taken is $2$.

Comment: You have the wrong value when the three variables are equal, it should be $\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$, which is bigger than $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{2x^2}{2\sqrt{x^2(1-x^2)}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{2x^2}{x^2+1-x^2}=2.$$
The equality occurs for $z=0$ and $x=y=\frac{1}{\sqrt2},$ which says that $2$ is a minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

You may convert it to become a function of two variables, the find the minimum value of that function. To do this, use

$$ 
z = \sqrt{1-(x^{2}+y^{2})} 
$$

And substitute this in

$$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}  + 
\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^{2}}}$$

so the function will be

$$
f(x,y) =  \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}  + 
\frac{ \sqrt{1-(x^{2}+y^{2})} }{ \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} } 
$$

Use partial derivatives to find the minimum value..?